# Flexbox flex-wrap is showing images flow over each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't seem to get `flex-wrap: row wrap` to work in the following code. The images just flow over each other instead of wrapping into new rows. What am I doing wrong? I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

You can see the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/delphinef/pen/GJmrzb):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h2>Featured Work</h2>
</div>
<div class="row bottom">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaLm.gif">
    <h3>APPIFY</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaLm.gif">
    <h3>SUNFLOWER</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaLm.gif">
    <h3>BOKEH</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you enforce a 33% width, even if the content is wider:

```css
.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

Instead, use a `min-width`. Then, the flex items will be allowed to grow more than that if their content is wider.

```css
.col-4 {
  min-width: 33.33%;
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.col-4 {
  min-width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h2>Featured Work</h2>
</div>
<div class="row bottom">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaLm.gif">
    <h3>APPIFY</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaLm.gif">
    <h3>SUNFLOWER</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfaLm.gif">
    <h3>BOKEH</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```